# Adding a footer view in RECYCLER VIEW?

Tags: android, android-adapter, android-recyclerview

i want to add a footer layout at the base of the recycler view.Below is my adapter view which inflates header layout as well as other items as well.Help appreciated!

```
public class SplitMembersAdapter extends RecyclerViewAdapter<SplitMember, SplitMemberViewHolder> {

        private final ArrayList<SplitMember> mSplitMembersList;
        private final ImageLoader mImageLoader;
        private static final int TYPE_HEADER = 0;
        private static final int TYPE_ITEM = 1;
        private int splitAmount;
        private boolean isAmountSplitted;

        public SplitMembersAdapter(ArrayList<SplitMember> members,ImageLoader imageLoader) {
            mSplitMembersList = members;
            mImageLoader = imageLoader;
        }

        @Override
        public int getItemCount() {
            return mSplitMembersList.size();
        }

        @Override
        public int getItemViewType(int position) {
            if (isPositionHeader(position)) {
                return TYPE_HEADER;
            }

            return TYPE_ITEM;
        }

        private static boolean isPositionHeader(int position) {
            return position == 0;
        }

        @Override
        public SplitMemberViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup viewGroup, int viewType) {
            View itemView = LayoutInflater.from(viewGroup.getContext()).
                    inflate(R.layout.split_member_item_layout, viewGroup, false);
            return new SplitMemberViewHolder(itemView);
        }

        @Override
        public void onBindViewHolder(SplitMemberViewHolder viewHolder, int position) {
            SplitMember contact = mSplitMembersList.get(position);
            viewHolder.splitMemAmount.setText(String.format("%.2f", contact.getShare()));
            viewHolder.splitMemberColor.setBackgroundColor(contact.getColor());
            if (position == TYPE_HEADER){
                viewHolder.splitMemName.setText("You");
                mImageLoader.loadImage(contact.getImg(),
                        viewHolder.splitMemImg, R.drawable.empty_user_placeholder);
            }


            else {
                viewHolder.splitMemName.setText(contact.getName());
                mImageLoader.loadImage(Utils.getProfileImageUrl(contact.getImg()),
                        viewHolder.splitMemImg,R.drawable.empty_user_placeholder);
            }

        }
    }

    class SplitMemberViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

        public BezelImageView splitMemImg;
        public TextView splitMemName;
        public TextView splitMemAmount;
        public View splitMemberColor;

        public SplitMemberViewHolder(View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            splitMemberColor = itemView.findViewById(R.id.member_color);
            splitMemImg = (BezelImageView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.member_profile_image);
            splitMemName = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.member_name);
            splitMemAmount = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.member_amount);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I created a wrapper around my adapter using [this gist](https://gist.github.com/sebnapi/fde648c17616d9d3bcde).And after that i can include my own layout and viewholder for my header and footer as well as the rest of the items.

```
    public class SplitMembersAdapter extends HeaderFooterRecyclerViewAdapter  implements  AutoCompleteContactTextView.ContactSelectListener{

        private final ArrayList<SplitMember> mSplitMembersList;
        private final ImageLoader mImageLoader;
        private static final int TYPE_HEADER = 0;
        private static final int TYPE_ITEM = 1;
        private static final int TYPE_FOOTER = 2;
        private int splitAmount;
        private boolean isAmountSplitted;

        public SplitMembersAdapter(ArrayList<SplitMember> members, ImageLoader imageLoader) {
            mSplitMembersList = members;
            mImageLoader = imageLoader;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean useFooter() {
            return true;
        }

        @Override
        public RecyclerView.ViewHolder onCreateFooterViewHolder(ViewGroup viewGroup, int viewType) {
            View itemView = LayoutInflater.from(viewGroup.getContext()).
                    inflate(R.layout.split_member_footer_layout, viewGroup, false);
            return new SplitMemberFooterViewHolder(itemView);
        }


//Binding data wrt to footer
        @Override
        public void onBindFooterView(final RecyclerView.ViewHolder holder, int position) {
            if (holder instanceof SplitMemberFooterViewHolder){
                ((SplitMemberFooterViewHolder) holder).mAddFriends.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View v) {
                        ((SplitMemberFooterViewHolder) holder).mAddFriendPlaceholderTxt.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                        ((SplitMemberFooterViewHolder) holder).mAddFriends.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                        ((SplitMemberFooterViewHolder) holder).mPhoneEnterView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    }
                });

                ((SplitMemberFooterViewHolder) holder).mPhoneEnterView.setmContactSelectListener(this);
                ((SplitMemberFooterViewHolder) holder).mPhoneEnterView.setDisplayPhoto(true);
                ((SplitMemberFooterViewHolder) holder).mPhoneEnterView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View view) {
                        ((SplitMemberFooterViewHolder) holder).mPhoneEnterView.setCursorVisible(true);
                    }
                });
                ((SplitMemberFooterViewHolder) holder).mPhoneEnterView.setOnKeyListener(new View.OnKeyListener() {
                    @Override
                    public boolean onKey(View view, int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
                        if (event.getAction() == KeyEvent.ACTION_UP)
                        {
                            switch (keyCode)
                            {
                                case KeyEvent.KEYCODE_DPAD_CENTER:
                                case KeyEvent.KEYCODE_ENTER:

                                    postContact(((SplitMemberFooterViewHolder) holder)
                                            .mPhoneEnterView.getText().toString());

                                    return true;
                                default:
                                    break;
                            }
                        }
                        return false;
                    }
                });


            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onContactSelect(People contact) {
            String mobileNum = String.valueOf(contact.getData());
            postContact(mobileNum);
        }

        private static void postContact(String contact) {
            EventBus.getDefault().post(new Events(Events.GET_CONTACT,
                    true, contact));
        }

        @Override
        public RecyclerView.ViewHolder onCreateBasicItemViewHolder(ViewGroup viewGroup, int viewType) {
            View itemView = LayoutInflater.from(viewGroup.getContext()).
                    inflate(R.layout.split_member_item_layout, viewGroup, false);
            return new SplitMemberViewHolder(itemView);
        }
    //Binding data wrt the items
        @Override
        public void onBindBasicItemView(RecyclerView.ViewHolder holder, int position) {
            SplitMember contact = mSplitMembersList.get(position);

            if (holder instanceof SplitMemberViewHolder){
                ((SplitMemberViewHolder) holder).splitMemAmount.setText(String.format("%.2f", contact.getShare()));
                ((SplitMemberViewHolder) holder).splitMemberColor.setBackgroundColor(contact.getColor());
                if (position == TYPE_HEADER) {
                    ((SplitMemberViewHolder) holder).splitMemName.setText("You");
                    mImageLoader.loadImage(contact.getImg(),
                            ((SplitMemberViewHolder) holder).splitMemImg, R.drawable.empty_user_placeholder);
                }  else {
                    ((SplitMemberViewHolder) holder).splitMemName.setText(contact.getName());
                    mImageLoader.loadImage(Utils.getProfileImageUrl(contact.getImg()),
                            ((SplitMemberViewHolder) holder).splitMemImg, R.drawable.empty_user_placeholder);
                }
            }
        }


        @Override
        public int getBasicItemCount() {
            return  mSplitMembersList.size();
        }

        @Override
        public int getBasicItemType(int position) {
            return position;
        }


    }

//Seperate viewholders for different footer as well as items
    class SplitMemberViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

        public BezelImageView splitMemImg;
        public TextView splitMemName;
        public TextView splitMemAmount;
        public View splitMemberColor;

        public SplitMemberViewHolder(View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            splitMemberColor = itemView.findViewById(R.id.member_color);
            splitMemImg = (BezelImageView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.member_profile_image);
            splitMemName = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.member_name);
            splitMemAmount = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.member_amount);
        }
    }class SplitMemberFooterViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

        public BezelImageView mAddFriends;
        public AutoCompleteContactTextView mPhoneEnterView;
        public TextView mAddFriendPlaceholderTxt;

        public SplitMemberFooterViewHolder(View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            mAddFriends = (BezelImageView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.add_friends_img);
            mPhoneEnterView = (AutoCompleteContactTextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.add_member_edit_text);
            mAddFriendPlaceholderTxt = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.add_friend_static_txt);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 5):

Similar to to adding the header add the footer too.

```
public class SplitMembersAdapter extends RecyclerViewAdapter<SplitMember, SplitMemberViewHolder> {

        private final ArrayList<SplitMember> mSplitMembersList;
        private final ImageLoader mImageLoader;
        private static final int TYPE_HEADER = 0;
        private static final int TYPE_ITEM = 1;
        private static final int TYPE_FOOTER = 2;
        private int splitAmount;
        private boolean isAmountSplitted;

        public SplitMembersAdapter(ArrayList<SplitMember> members,ImageLoader imageLoader) {
            mSplitMembersList = members;
            mImageLoader = imageLoader;
        }

        @Override
        public int getItemCount() {
            return mSplitMembersList.size();
        }

        @Override
        public int getItemViewType(int position) {
            if (isPositionHeader(position)) {
                return TYPE_HEADER;
            }ELSE if (isPositionFooter(position)) {
                return TYPE_Footer;
            }
            return TYPE_ITEM;
        }

        private static boolean isPositionHeader(int position) {
            return position == 0;
        }

        private static boolean isPositionFooter(int position) {
            return position == mSplitMembersList.size()-1;
        }

        @Override
        public SplitMemberViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup viewGroup, int viewType) {

            switch(viewType){
               case TYPE_HEADER:
                 //return header view holder;
               break;
               case TYPE_ITEM:
                 //return item view holder;
                break;
               case TYPE_FOOTER:   
                 //return footer view holder;
               break;
           }
        }

        @Override
        public void onBindViewHolder(SplitMemberViewHolder viewHolder, int position) {
               switch(getItemViewType(position)){
               case TYPE_HEADER:
                 //bind header data;
               break;
               case TYPE_ITEM:
                 //bind item data
                break;
               case TYPE_FOOTER:   
                 //bind footer data.
               break;
           }
        }
    }

    class SplitMemberViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

        public BezelImageView splitMemImg;
        public TextView splitMemName;
        public TextView splitMemAmount;
        public View splitMemberColor;

        public SplitMemberViewHolder(View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            splitMemberColor = itemView.findViewById(R.id.member_color);
            splitMemImg = (BezelImageView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.member_profile_image);
            splitMemName = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.member_name);
            splitMemAmount = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.member_amount);
        }
    }
```

Comment: How to do you call this from your code outside the adapter class? Like in case of ListView we call lv.removeFooterView(loadMoreView); and lv.addFooterView(loadMoreView);

Comment: Simply set this adapter to the RecyclerView, then this adapter will take care of adding the header and footer. It can differnetiate the header and footer by using getItemViewType(int position).  @erdomester