# How to add footerView at the end of Recyclerview in android?

Tags: android

I have an app which contain recyclerview with ads in between recyclerview and Losing progress as footer at bottom of recyclerview when i scroll at bottom of recyclerview it is adding more data in dataset all is working fine but problem is with adding loading progress at bottom .Pls help me out from this problem as i tried many times but not getting success.

MainActivity:-

```
contacts = new ArrayList<>();
    random = new Random();
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        Contact contact = new Contact();
        contact.setPhone(phoneNumberGenerating());
        contact.setEmail("DevExchanges" + i + "@gmail.com");
        contact.setViewType(1);
        contacts.add(contact);
    }
    //Place two Admob Ads in recyclerview
    Contact myString1 = new Contact();
    myString1.setViewType(2);
    contacts.add(3, myString1);

    contactAdapter = new ContactAdapter(recyclerView, contacts, this);
    recyclerView.setAdapter(contactAdapter);

    //set load more listener for the RecyclerView adapter
    contactAdapter.setOnLoadMoreListener(new OnLoadMoreListener() {
        @Override
        public void onLoadMore() {
            if (contacts.size() <= 20) {
                contacts.add(null);
                contactAdapter.notifyItemInserted(contacts.size() - 1);
                new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        contacts.remove(contacts.size() - 1);
                        contactAdapter.notifyItemRemoved(contacts.size());

                        //Generating more data
                        int index = contacts.size();
                        int end = index + 2;
                        for (int i = index; i < end; i++) {
                            Contact contact = new Contact();
                            contact.setPhone(phoneNumberGenerating());
                            contact.setEmail("DevExchanges" + i + "@gmail.com");
                            contact.setViewType(1);
                            contacts.add(contact);
                        }
                        //Place one Admob Ads in recyclerview
                        Contact myString1 = new Contact();
                        myString1.setViewType(2);
                        contacts.add(3, myString1);

                        contactAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                        contactAdapter.setLoaded();
                    }
                }, 5000);
            } else {
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Loading data completed", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        }
    });
}
```

adapter code:-

```
  @Override
public int getItemViewType(int position) {
    if (position == contacts.size()) {
        // footer_view to check in your switch/case
        return 3;
    }
    return contacts.get(position).getViewType();
}

@Override
public RecyclerView.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    RecyclerView.ViewHolder viewHolder = null;
    LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext());
    switch (viewType) {
        case 1:
            View itemView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.item_recycler_view_row, parent, false);
            viewHolder = new UserViewHolder(itemView);
            break;
        case 2:
            View adView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.item_three, parent, false);
            viewHolder = new ItemThree(adView);
            break;
        case 3:
            View loading = inflater.inflate(R.layout.item_loading, parent, false);
            viewHolder = new LoadingViewHolder(loading);
            break;
    }
    return viewHolder;
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(RecyclerView.ViewHolder holder, int position) {

    switch (holder.getItemViewType()) {
        case 1:
            Contact contact = contacts.get(position);
            UserViewHolder userViewHolder = (UserViewHolder) holder;
            userViewHolder.phone.setText(contact.getEmail());
            userViewHolder.email.setText(contact.getPhone());
            break;
        case 2:
            ItemThree itemThree = (ItemThree) holder;
            itemThree.textView.setText("ADs");
            break;
        case 3:
            LoadingViewHolder loadingViewHolder = (LoadingViewHolder) holder;
            loadingViewHolder.progressBar.setIndeterminate(true);
            break;
    }
}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return contacts.size()+1;
}
```

Comment: refer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30570106/adding-a-footer-view-in-recycler-view

Comment: But i set Google and facebook view in Dataset of Recyclerview

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add one item count for footer,

```
@Override
public int getItemCount() {
     return s_oDataset.size() + 1;
}
```

Add this case to onCreateViewHolder

```
case CFooterView.m_kARTICLE_TYPE_FOOTER:
            View contentView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.footer, parent, false);
            viewHolder = new FooterViewHolder(contentView);
            break;
```

Add this to onBindViewHolder

```
case CFooterView.m_kARTICLE_TYPE_FOOTER:
                //Do whatever you want with your footerviewHolder
                break;
```

Change this code:

```
contactAdapter.setOnLoadMoreListener(new OnLoadMoreListener() {
    @Override
    public void onLoadMore() {
        if (contacts.size() <= 20) {

            new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {

                    //Generating more data
                    int index = contacts.size();
                    int end = index + 2;
                    for (int i = index; i < end; i++) {
                        Contact contact = new Contact();
                        contact.setPhone(phoneNumberGenerating());
                        contact.setEmail("DevExchanges" + i + "@gmail.com");
                        contact.setViewType(1);
                        contacts.add(contact);
                    }
                    //Place one Admob Ads in recyclerview
                    Contact myString1 = new Contact();
                    myString1.setViewType(2);
                    contacts.add(3, myString1);

                    contactAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                    contactAdapter.setLoaded();
                }
            }, 5000);
        } else {
            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Loading data completed", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    }
});
```

Update these things in your code:

```
//Take a field in adapter
public boolean isItemLoadingCompleted;

//set this field to true when loading completed, where you are showing toast
contactAdapter.isItemLoadingCompleted=true;

//update onBindViewHolder
if(itemLoadingCompleted) {
    loadingViewHolder.progressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
} else {
    loadingViewHolder.progressBar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
}
```

Comment: and what about getViewType

Comment: what to do in this method

Comment: in java.lang.NullPointerException
                                                                                           at info.devexchanges.endlessrecyclerview.ContactAdapter.getItemViewType(ContactAdapter.java:56)

Comment: return contacts.get(position).getViewType();

Comment: in onBindViewHolder replace switch (holder.getItemViewType()) with switch (getItemViewType()). If problem not solve than tell me which line giving error.

Comment: it is giving error in  java.lang.NullPointerException
                                                                                           at info.devexchanges.endlessrecyclerview.ContactAdapter.getItemViewType(ContactAdapter.java:56)

Comment: in line return contacts.get(position).getViewType();

Comment: Debug that line and see the value of `getViewType()`, I think it is returning null value. and why are you doing this `contacts.remove(contacts.size() - 1)`, if you are doing this for removing footer than remember your footer is not added in your list so there is no need to do this.

Comment: then what to do shall i remove contacts.remove(contacts.size() - 1)

Comment: i have remove contacts.remove(contacts.size() - 1);
                            contactAdapter.notifyItemRemoved(contacts.size());

Comment: and also debug that line then got arrlist:11: position:0

Comment: actuall i i have to do is when i scroll to end of recyclerview loading progress must be visble and and add more data that why i add that line

Comment: getting 1 when debugged

Comment: but when i scroll to end t gets crashed

Comment: I have inserted code in my answer, just copy and paste it.

Comment: It is working but loading does not get invisible when condition comes to Toas message "Loading complete

Comment: Loading not getting invisisble when condition falls on                     Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Loading data completed", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

Comment: where to put in adapter or in activity

Comment: Sure Brother you don't know what you did .................Very very thankfule to you....