# position a view below RecyclerView's last child

Tags: android, android-layout, android-recyclerview, android-xml

So I have a `RecyclerView` and I want to position a view below its last child.

**The behavior should be as follows**:
I scroll the `RecyclerView` down (The view is not shown yet) and when i get to the last child, the view should be below this child. when i scroll up, the view should be scrolled too and not be shown.

What I tried so far are some bad tries and the best of them is this:
(the view is not shown until I scroll to the bottom but when I scroll up the view stick at the bottom of the screen)

```
<ScrollView
  android:layout_width="match_parent"
  android:layout_height="match_parent">
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical">
        <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
            android:id="@+id/home_recipes"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
        <com.wang.avi.AVLoadingIndicatorView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            app:indicatorName="BallPulseIndicator"
            app:indicatorColor="@color/colorAccent"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            />
    </LinearLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

Comment: There is no such thing like `addFooter` in `RecyclerView` so you have to add an extra item to DataSet to show the footer . Have a look at [This duplicate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30570106/adding-a-footer-view-in-recycler-view) or Similar .

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Android 5.0 - Add header/footer to a RecyclerView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26448717/android-5-0-add-header-footer-to-a-recyclerview)